# Problems properly structure a project C ++ / QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a project in which I collaborate with other programmers. My part is to perform a Web user interface. I mean, my application exchanges "jsons" with a web to interact with the application you are doing in Qt.

My module must interpret the json that I receive, and as may be, execute the instructions that my colleagues are doing (objects).

I do not know how many modules will finally in the application, and therefore the number of possible instructions must be easily apliable or changeable.

I thought about making a structure with a list of pointers to objects that believe my teammates. Access to this list, get the pointer that interests me and execute the methods of these objects according to the instruction you have received.

I try structure my Qt/C++ project and use a global variable of type "struct".

I do something as this:

**file "common.h"**

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QCryptographicHash>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
....
#include <QString>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTime>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef LISTOFUSERS_H
  #include <listofusers.h>
#endif
#ifndef RECOLECTORMODBUS_H
  #include <RecolectorRTU/recolectormodbus.h>
#endif

//CONSTANTES GLOBALES. - global constants

#define LENGTH_TOKEN 15
#define MAX_INACTIVITY_TIME 60

/*
* WARNING: CUIDADO AL ACCEDER A ESTOS PUNTEROS Y VARIABLES DESDE
* DIFERENTES HILOS.
* Careful to access a this pointers and variables from diferents threads.
*/

//Listado de punteros a los objetos principales que se usan en el proyecto.
//list of pointers to principals objects that use in de project.
extern struct pointersToModules containerOfModules;  // <------ I'VE A ERROR HERE


#endif // COMMON
```

In **common.cpp** I've this:

```
#include <common.h>


//Listado de punteros de los módulos que se usarán en el proyecto.
struct pointersToModules {
    listofusers *pntToListOfUsers;
    recolectorModbus *pntToRecolector; //TEMPORAL: solo pruebas, only test
};
```

All other class files are how this:

**class1.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H_
#define CLASS1_H_

#include "common.h"

class myclass1 {
.....
};
```

**class1.cpp**

```
#include "class1.h"

myclass1::myclass1 {
....
}
```

I want have a header file that include in all others files. As I do this in my *php* projects.

But I've a problem in "common.h". When I try compile, give me this error:

```
error: forward declaration of 'struct pointersToModules'
extern struct pointersToModules containerOfModules;
              ^
```

But I believe that I only declared the global variable (`extern struct pointersToModules containerOfModules;`) in "common.h" and defined the structure in "common.cpp"

I don't like this, but I try defined the structure in "common.h" and the error that the compiler give me is:

```
error: 'listofusers' does not name a type
listofusers *pntToListOfUsers;
^
```

I don't understand the problem. If you can explain this me, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you write `struct` definitions *not* in the headers?
Just move

```
struct pointersToModules {
    listofusers *pntToListOfUsers;
    recolectorModbus *pntToRecolector; //TEMPORAL: solo pruebas, only test
};
```

to common.h above

```
extern struct pointersToModules containerOfModules;
```

and the error should be gone.
(You *did* include listofusers.h, so I don´t quite believe the other error. Try again)

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the definition of your `struct pointersToModules` in a header file.
If the header file is not `common.h` or you don't want to include it there, you can do a forward declaration as such:

**common.h**

```
// Code
struct pointersToModules;
// More code
pointersToModules *ptmObject;
```

**common.cpp**

```
#include "pointers_to_modules.h"
// Code
ptmObject->pntToListOfUsers->process;
```